# Google Drive PDFViewer is not loading PDF file

Tags: android

Hi I have an odd problem. I have an android application with PDF files bundled with the apk. On the UI I display a table list of the files and user can click and load the pdf file with a viewer they choose. On 5.x.x it is working fine with Google Drive which is installed by default. However on marshmallow (6.x) I am getting a permission denied when choosing Google Drive to open the file. Here is what I am doing, I copy it first to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and then passing on the File object to Intent as below. One more wrinkle, if I choose DropBox viewer during opening, it works. If I choose OfficeSuite it works. But Google Drive and Microsoft OneDrive fails to open the same file. Given that Marshmallow permission model has changed, my assumption at this point is that DropBox and OfficeSuite probably has higher degree of permissions on Marshmallow? Thanks

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // Not needed?
```

Here are the log entries

```
    11-24 19:51:34.446 879-897/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity: +522ms
    11-24 19:51:34.449 3558-3558/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
    11-24 19:51:34.533 3180-3190/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23577(1876KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 909us total 103.503ms
    11-24 19:51:34.743 8782-9759/? E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
    11-24 19:51:34.743 8782-9759/? E/PdfLoader: Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : 008AlAnfaal.pdf] +UriOpenable, uri: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.eicsanjose.qicsea3/cache/008AlAnfaal.pdf
    11-24 19:51:34.831 879-12253/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{com.google.android.music/com.google.android.music.dial.DialMediaRouteProviderService} from pid=4391, uid=10143 that is not exported from uid 10060
    11-24 19:51:34.887 879-2823/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Forget the Storage Permission Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C28pvd2plBA) (and [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/ianhanniballake/forget-the-storage-permission-alternatives-for-sharing-and-collaborating)) and the [sharing files training](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html), you should **not** be sending a file URI to other apps as it assumes that other apps have the read storage permission. You should instead use a [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to create a URI that all apps can read, with or without the storage permission.